# How to stream Data between Unity Projects

Tags: unity-game-engine, mrtk, openvr

**Question**

I plan to have 2 Unity Projects (so that I can target different builds). 
I'm looking for a simple and fast way to stream data between the two.

The first Project is using standalone with OpenVr and the other is using UWP together with MRTK. 
I essentially want to send events back and forth between the 2.

**Context:**

I want to use Vive Trackers and remote a scene to the Hololens, where Gameobjects follow the position of the Vive Trackers. Vive Trackers require SteamVr and OpenVr. Apparently, they are not compatible with the MRTK: 
https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/5754

Which brings me either to 2 Unity Projects where I (hopefully) can easily send data back and forth or to Peer-to-Peer/Server-Client Solution. 
However, I couldn't an easy and quick solution for the latter, but you can prove me wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You could create build scripts that can setup different XR-Settings and build different scenes for different targets. Then use networking for communication between the builds.

That would eliminate the hassle having two different projects with the same content.

The [Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer.html) is a good start to see what is possible and how it is done.

Comment: By networking do you mean UNet (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNet.html)? Or what would be your approach?

Comment: UNet got deprecated, but you can look into [Mirror](https://github.com/vis2k/Mirror).